# Capybara 'visit' method unrecognized outside spec/features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When upgrading to Capybara 2.1.0 I cant use the `visit` method in spec/support (got `undefined method 'visit'`).

Code as follows:

```
include ApplicationHelper
include SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email-signin",     with: user.email
  fill_in "Password-signin",  with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
end
```

I tried `get` instead of the `visit` but I also got `undefined method 'get'`.

Is there any other method I can use?

Edit:
I'm using Ruby 4.0.0 and Capybara 2.1.0.
Capybara made a change in 2.1.0 so that their DSL is only available in spec/features and since this function is written in spec/support I can't access the DSL of Capybara. I don't mind that, thats why I searched for `visit` alternatives.

**Workaround:**
I added `include Capybara::DSL` in the top. However, I got `including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!` which I agree with and I want to change/improve it. So, for now its a quick fix.

Comment: Do you have any capybara functionality working? Just wondering if your gem is installed correctly.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414423/rails-capybara-not-working

Comment: see edit. capybara works fine in spec/features