# Rails Capybara not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying to run a simple test using rspec and capybara:

```
describe "Create" do
  visit new_client_path 

  page.should have_selector('h1', text: "New Client") 
end
```

However i get error:

```
undefined local variable or method `visit'
```

And if i remove the visit line i get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `page'
```

I have included the DSL in the `spec_helper` file.

what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you simply forgot to put your test inside the `it` block:

```
describe "Create" do
  it "does something" do
    visit new_client_path 
    page.should have_selector('h1', text: "New Client") 
  end
end
```

Comment: had to clean my gems and reinstall `capybara` and `it` block works now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Rails 3 and RSpec, have you placed your specs in features instead of requests? You shouldn't need to include the DSL if you are using features directory.

Also check that you have latest version of the gems.

From https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara:

> Using Capybara with RSpec
>
> Load RSpec 2.x support by adding the following line (typically to your
>   spec_helper.rb file):
>
> require 'capybara/rspec' **If you are using Rails, put your Capybara
>   specs in spec/features.**

Comment: i added the DSL as a way of debugging the problem, i also tried to give the spec a type of feature and added `require 'capybara/spec' but with no luck